# Content Search Web Part - Sort by Scheduled publishing date

Tags: date-time, sorting, content-search-web-part, cross-site-publishing

I am a developer working to transfer a wordpress site to SharePoint 2013 using cross site publishing.  This means an authoring site to create pages, and a publishing site to display them.
On the authoring site I have pages in a list with scheduled publishing enabled.  These pages are crawled by the publishing site, and I am displaying data about them in a content search web part.  All of this works, it is just background.

By default, it appears the query for the web part sorts by the created date of these pages.  I need to sort them by their Publishing Start Date.  When transferring old articles from wordpress, they need to retain their original order.

When editing the query through the SharePoint UI, I press "change query".  In advanced mode, I go to the sorting tab.  Even though the Publishing start date has a managed property, it isn't in this list.  Any idea of how I can make it sort by the Publishing Start Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you create custom result resource for your data, select the result source you have created while building the query and see if you can see the Publishing start date under sorting section of query builder. I hope you have set the managed property to be sortable.

Comment: I had not set the property to sortable, and now it appears in the sorting section of the query builder.  Unfortunately, the sorting doesn't work.  The PublishingStartDateOWSDATE hold the data I need, but it is a text field.  Is there a way to treat it like a date for sorting?

Comment: This was a problem with my query somewhere.  recreating the web part with the new field chosen in sorting worked, so I'm marking your answer as the solution